# Using an array of vars name to call a function

Tags: php, arrays

I want to use an array in order to call a function.

Firstly, I'm getting a form via post, so I have something like this.

```
$var1="red";
$var2="blue";
$var3="Mary";
$varN="Ted";
```

I have created an array like this:

```
$variables=array("$var1", "$var2", "$var3", "$varN");
```

I want to use this array to call another function, in fact it is a MySQL query. So I want to get this result using the array:

```
addToTable($var1, $var2, $var3, varN);
```

Is it posible?

The reason I'm doing this is because I will introduce a multiple quantity of entries in the table, it's a variable number of entries and the array var names will change. For the next round I will introduce in the query something similar to this:

```
addToTable($var1_2, $var2_2, $var3_2, varN_2);
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. You're trying to send these 4 parameters $var1, $var2, $var3, varN..so what? What's the issue? What does the function look like?

Comment: I have at least 37 parameters. Everytime I add a row it multiplies. The case I exposed is just an example, if there were only 4 variables i wouldnt be doing an array.

Comment: It's an awful practice to pass so many parameters. Why don't you pass an array?

Comment: It is a waste of processing power and execution time to wrap variables in quotes, `"$var1"` is tersely inefficient, you just need the variable: `array($var1,$var2,$varN);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as array to the function and do a `foreach` inside the function.

Your variables:

```
$variables = array($var1, $var2, $var3, $varN);
```

The function:

```
function addToTable($array = [])
{
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      // Do stuff here
   }
}
```

And you call the function like this:

```
addToTable($variables);
```

Comment: But how can i do to introduce for example var1_1, var2_1, etc...?

Comment: @Ironlord, you call the function again: `$variables = [$var1_1, $var2_1, $var3_1, $varN_1];` `addToTable($variables);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array of arguments to a function using `call_user_func_array()`.

```
function addToTable($a, $b, $c, $d)
{
    return "{$a}-{$b}-{$c}-{$d}";
}

$var1 = 'red';
$var2 = 'blue';
$var3 = 'Mary';
$varN = 'Ted';

$arguments = array($var1, $var2, $var3, $varN);
$x = call_user_func_array('addToTable', $arguments);

echo $x; // red-blue-Mary-Ted
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `call_user_func_array()` already mentioned above, since 5.6 you can also perform similar actions via:

#### Variadic Functions

In which you can pass any number of values to a function, which collects them into an iterable argument:

```php
function foo(...$arguments)
{
    foreach ($arguments as $arg) {
        echo $arg . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```

Yields:

```
1
2
3
```

This is vaguely similar to passing in an array or `call_user_func_array()` - albeit more flexible - for instance, you can use typehinting:

```
function foo(array ...$arguments)
{
    //
}

foo([], [], []); // works, each argument is an array
foo(1, 2, 3);    // fatal error!
```

#### Argument Unpacking

As stated in the [release docs](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) Argument Unpacking does the following:

> Arrays and Traversable objects can be unpacked into argument lists when calling functions by using the ... operator. This is also known as the splat operator in other languages, including Ruby.

This is useful if you already have an array of values that you want to apply to a function with an explicit argument list. This is probably the best approach since it's explicit, and therefore easiest to reason about.

```php
function bar($a, $b, $c)
{
    echo $a . PHP_EOL;
    echo $b . PHP_EOL;
    echo $c . PHP_EOL;
}

$params = [1, 2, 3];
bar(...$params);
```

Yields:

```
1
2
3
```

Otherwise, if you are using <= 5.5, you could approximate the variadic approach with `func_get_args()`:

```
function baz()
{
    foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
        echo $arg . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

baz(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

PHP functions do not require functions to have explicit argument lists. However, I think it is harder to reason about a function that does not state its arguments explicitly, and it's harder to validate and use the arguments passed into it.

Hope this helps :)